# Grouping closer times in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, query

I want group closer times (time gap should not exceeded 2 min). What I mean is to group the records which have a time gap less than 10 min. And return min and max time of each group.

How it is possible in SQL Server?

This is my sample data:

| message_time | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-12-14 10:07:49.358739 | 11 |
| 2020-12-14 10:08:16.156553 | 11 |
| 2020-12-14 10:08:32.195645 | 11 |
| 2020-12-14 13:36:16.103253 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 13:46:43.871769 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 13:50:42.867178 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 13:55:30.530697 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 13:56:42.472823 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 13:57:05.880580 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 13:57:40.377021 | 4 |
| 2020-12-14 13:58:12.723215 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 14:34:30.633401 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 10:16:18.188387 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 10:16:30.735493 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 10:18:03.501372 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 12:50:46.953427 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 12:51:11.772787 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 12:59:34.264237 | 11 |
| 2020-12-15 13:02:10.622184 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 10:28:27.489880 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 10:28:43.793308 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 19:29:56.208375 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 19:45:34.401379 | 12 |

This is my expected result

| Min | Max | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-12-14 10:07:49.358739 | 2020-12-14 10:08:32.195645 | 11 |
| 2020-12-14 13:36:16.103253 | 2020-12-14 13:36:16.103253 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 13:46:43.871769 | 2020-12-14 13:58:12.723215 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 13:57:40.377021 | 2020-12-14 13:57:40.377021 | 4 |
| 2020-12-14 14:34:30.633401 | 2020-12-14 14:34:30.633401 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 10:16:18.188387 | 2020-12-15 10:18:03.501372 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 12:50:46.953427 | 2020-12-15 12:51:11.772787 | 4 |
| 2020-12-15 12:59:34.264237 | 2020-12-15 12:59:34.264237 | 11 |
| 2020-12-15 13:02:10.622184 | 2020-12-15 13:02:10.622184 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 10:28:27.489880 | 2020-12-14 19:29:56.208375 | 12 |
| 2020-12-14 19:45:34.401379 | 2020-12-14 19:45:34.401379 | 12 |

*In this table diffreents between the dates in each group should not exceed 10 min

Comment: *diffreents between the dates in each group should not exceed 10 min* If so then the island range is dynamic. Recursive CTE seems to be the only reasonable option.

Comment: How would you group 3 records with the following `message_times`: `2020-12-14 9:00:00.000`, `2020-12-14 9:08:00.000`, and `2020-12-14 9:12:00.000`?...The first one is within 10 minutes of the second one, the second one is within 10 minutes of the third one, but the third one is more than 10 minutes away from the first one. What do you expect the output to be in such a scenario?

Comment: I’m not going to try to answer this right now, because I’m just writing on my phone, but... using a series of CTEs or a series of nested sub-queries... start by making a column in which you compare message_time to its LAG (partitioned by user_id). If the gap is less than ten minutes, make it 0. Otherwise 1. Then in the next CTE (or level of nested subq), get the rolling sum of this column. Then group on that rolling sum.

Answer (score 1):

a couple of notes, seems Rob Farley would also write something similar (I just read his comment now). Secondly I missed your 10 minute rule - I'm going to leave some of the fun for you too

/*

```
create table #t (msgtime datetime2, userid int)

insert #t values ('2020-12-14 10:07:49.358739',11)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 10:08:16.156553',11)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 10:08:32.195645',11)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 13:36:16.103253',12)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 13:46:43.871769',12)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 13:50:42.867178',12)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 13:55:30.530697',12)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 13:56:42.472823',12)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 13:57:05.880580',12)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 13:57:40.377021',4)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 13:58:12.723215',12)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 14:34:30.633401',4)
insert #t values ('2020-12-15 10:16:18.188387',4)
insert #t values ('2020-12-15 10:16:30.735493',4)
insert #t values ('2020-12-15 10:18:03.501372',4)
insert #t values ('2020-12-15 12:50:46.953427',4)
insert #t values ('2020-12-15 12:51:11.772787',4)
insert #t values ('2020-12-15 12:59:34.264237',11)
insert #t values ('2020-12-15 13:02:10.622184',12)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 10:28:27.489880',12)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 10:28:43.793308',12)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 19:29:56.208375',12)
insert #t values ('2020-12-14 19:45:34.401379',12)

select * from #t order by userid, msgtime

*/

;with times as 
(select t1.userid, t1.msgtime as prevmsgtime , 
    LEAD(msgtime, 1, NULL) OVER
    (
       Partition By UserID
        ORDER BY
            msgtime
    ) AS nextmsgtime 
from #t t1
)
, seq as
(
select 
userid, 
prevmsgtime , 
nextmsgtime , 
datediff(mi, prevmsgtime , nextmsgtime ) as timediff,
-- If nextmsgtime is null wwe have changed userid 
-- or it the time difference is more than 2 mins - a new group
case when (nextmsgtime  is null) or (datediff(mi, prevmsgtime , nextmsgtime ) > 2)
then convert(int,1)
else convert(int,0)
end as newseq
from times
where datediff(mi, prevmsgtime , nextmsgtime ) is not null

)
,
grouper as 
(
select 
userid, 
prevmsgtime  as prevmsgtime ,
nextmsgtime  as nextmsgtime ,
timediff,
newseq,
-- we can calculate a column to group by by summing up by user the number of times we start a new group
sum(newseq) over (partition by userid order by prevmsgtime ) as groupcol
from seq
)
-- get the min and max msgtime when we have a group
select 
userid,
min(prevmsgtime ) as prevmsgtime ,
max(nextmsgtime ) as nextmsgtime , 
count(*)+1 as nrows
from grouper
where newseq = 0
group by userid,groupcol
union all
-- just get the values if there isn't a group
select 
userid, 
prevmsgtime ,
nextmsgtime ,
1 as nrows
from grouper where newseq = 1
order by userid, prevmsgtime
```